# Printing a value of Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I tried to get the N*N matrix. to do that i used following code but printing a one value all the time. any idea to take the correct value of matrix.

I checked the destination mat using imread function which is not null. countervalue. But in the printf comes **\377** value which int count=0;

```
 Size s=destination.size();

    int count=0;
    for(int i=0 ;i<s.height; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<s.width; j++) {
            unsigned char* byte = destination.ptr<unsigned char>(i,j);
            count++;
            printf("valeue %s ",byte);
            printf("\n");

        }
    }
```

output

```
valeue \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377 .......
```

Comment: what is the output of `cout<<destination` ? Why are you casting unsigned char to char? Try changing `char byte` to `unsigned char byte`. Use %u for unsigned char.

Comment: @Rishit i still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't see any issue just by above code. Can you paste some more relevant code? what is output of `cout<<destination` ?

Comment: @Rishit when i prints my Mat object of destination i get the values 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 250, 173, 104, 187, 194, 193, 187, 181, 179, 178, 163, 152, 145, 134, 118, 118, 101, 83, 93, 77, 54, 60, 37, 54, 191, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255; 
Any idea to print these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ptr](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) accepts as argument the **row** number. You can thus get the pointer to the starting element of each row by calling pointer on each `i` (outside inner loop).

Then you need `%d` (or `%u`) in your `printf` (or you can use `cout`). Check the code below:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    int N = 10;

    // Init matrix
    Mat destination(N, N, CV_8UC1);
    randu(destination, Scalar(0), Scalar(255));

    Size s = destination.size();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<s.height; i++)
    {
        unsigned char* pByte = destination.ptr<unsigned char>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j<s.width; j++) {
            count++;
            printf("value %d ", pByte[j]);
            printf("\n");

            //cout << "value " << int(pByte[j]) << endl;
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

You can see in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31894250/5008845) other methods to get the value at specific position in a `Mat`.

Answer (score 0):

For printing the Mat values, you just need to iterate over Mat.

Here is some piece of code:

```
Mat in = imread("image.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if(in.empty())
{
  puts("Cannot open image!");
  return -1;
}
//Print the values
for(int i=0;i<in.rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<in.cols;j++)
    {
        cout<<in.at<uchar>(i,j)<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Here basically I am loading the image, checking whether it is empty or not, and then printing the values.

As my image is grayscale image, I have used `in.at<uchar>(i,j)` where `uchar` means `unsigned char`.