# OpenCV Mat data member access

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I've seen a lot of OpenCV code which accesses the data member of a `cv::Mat` directly. `cv::Mat` stores the pointer to the data in a `unsigned char* data` member. Access to the data member looks like:

```
cv::Mat matUC(3,3,CV_8U)
int rowIdx = 1;
int colIdx = 1;

unsigned char val = matUC.data[ rowIdx * matUC.cols + colIdx]
```

I'm wondering if this works for a `cv::Mat` with pixel type other than `unsigned char`.

```
cv::Mat matF(3,3,CV_32F)
int rowIdx = 1;
int colIdx = 1;

float val = matF.data[ rowIdx * matF.cols + colIdx];
```

My understanding would be that a typecast is needed to access the elements correctly. Something like:

```
float val = ((float*)matF.data)[ rowIdx * matF.cols + colIdx];
```

I've seen a lot of code which doesn't use a typecast. So my question is: Is the typecast mandatory to access the correct element?

Comment: Try:  `float val = matF.at<float>(rowIdx, colIdx);`

Comment: Note that `data[row * cols + col]` only works if the matrix `isContinuous()`. If you don't have that information, the safest way is to do `matrix.ptr<type>(row)[col]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Mat` data is an `uchar*`. If you have a, say, float matrix `CV_32FC1`, you need to access data as `float`.

You can do in different ways, not necessarily using casting:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat matF(3, 3, CV_32F);
    randu(matF, Scalar(0), Scalar(10));

    int rowIdx = 1;
    int colIdx = 1;

    // 1
    float f1 = matF.at<float>(rowIdx, colIdx);

    // 2
    float* fData2 = (float*)matF.data;
    float f2 = fData2[rowIdx*matF.step1() + colIdx];

    // 3
    float* fData3 = matF.ptr<float>(0);
    float f3 = fData3[rowIdx*matF.step1() + colIdx];

    // 4
    float* fData4 = matF.ptr<float>(rowIdx);
    float f4 = fData4[colIdx];

    // 5
    Mat1f mm(matF); // Or directly create like: Mat1f mm(3, 3);
    float f5 = mm(rowIdx, colIdx);

    // f1 == f2 == f3 == f4 == f5

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**

- it's better to use `step1()` instead of `cols` when accessing directly `data` through pointers, since the image may not be continuous. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33674655/5008845) for more details.
- The snippet is adapted from this [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31894250/5008845)

Comment: Is a Mat created like this `cv::Mat matF(3,3,CV_32F)` always guaranteed to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33674655/5008845) for more details.

Comment: This answers my question completely. Thanks for your effort!